# secure web server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ssl, client-server

I have a graphical user interface for my company product.
I want to secure the data being sent back and forth between client and server.

Is SSL one of the options? if yes, Please can some1 tell me the steps on how to implement it in my application code.

Do i need to buy the certificate or can i make it.. which is the best choice?

Any help is appreciated. thanks..

I am logging in using FormsAuthenticationTicket as follows:

```
Session["userName"] = UserName.Text;
                    Session["password"] = Password.Text;
                    Session["domain"] = Domain.Text;
                    string role = "Administrators";

                    // Create the authentication ticket
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,                          // version
                                                   UserName.Text,           // user name
                                                   DateTime.Now,               // creation
                                                   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),// Expiration
                                                   false,                      // Persistent 
                                                   role);         // User data

                    // Now encrypt the ticket.
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    // Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the
                    // cookie as data.
                    HttpCookie authCookie =
                                 new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                                encryptedTicket);

                    // Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                    // Redirect the user to the originally requested page 
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(UserName.Text, false));
```

I am not sure how secure this is?? any suggestions.

Comment: so i found this links..for SSL installation. hope it helps.

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Protect-Web-Servers-SSL.html

and   


http://security.fnal.gov/pki/webauthors.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is SSL one of the options?

It is the only sensible one

> if yes, Please can some1 tell me the steps on how to implement it in my application code.

Assuming you are dealing with a browser (as opposed to your own client applications that then communicates with the server via HTTP). You don't go near your application code with SSL (other than making sure your URIs are https ones).

You just install an SSL cert on the server.

> Do i need to buy the certificate or can i make it.. which is the best choice?

You can produce a self-signed cert, but this will generate scary warnings about trust in the user's browser. If the users are technically savvy or you have the resources to install the cert (and mark it as trusted) on all the clients before hand, this is fine. Otherwise you probably should buy one.

Comment: thank you so much for the well explained answer.. so if i go with SSL i dont need to make any changes in my present code?? I just buy the certificate and then do what.. if there are any further steps i need to follow to install please let me know. I ask this because i need to understand before i explain it to my manager. appreciate all the help

Comment: It depends on your server. I assume you use IIS, which I've managed to avoid for the last decade or so.

Answer (score 1):

Using authentication in your .net code will not secure the communication "on the wire." SSL is THE option of securing web traffic between a browser and the web server. You will need to purchase a secure certificate and configure your web server (not your ASP.NET application) to use the certificate.

Comment: thank you. so i dont make any change in my code? are any steps to install the SSL on server or a link of any kind that you kno of. it will be very helpful for me to start working on it.. thank you once again..

Answer (score 1):

SSL is indeed a possibility. Have a look at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813829

You do possibly need to alter code though (see link above).